# 'Spread' colors from red to purple (Hue: 0 - 255) evenly between unknown number of elements

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a webpage with a kind of list, I want the child elements of my list to have colors ranging for red to purple (red, orange, yellow, ..., purple) by using (preferably, but not necessarily) pure CSS.

So far the only method I have come up with, is using the `:nth-child` selector as follow:

```
.timeline-img:nth-child(1) {
    background: #F44336; /* red */
}
.timeline-img:nth-child(2) {
    background: #E91E63; /* pink */
}
.timeline-img:nth-child(3) {
    background: #9C27B0; /* purple */
}
.timeline-img:nth-child(4) {
    background: #673AB7; /* deep purple */
}
.timeline-img:nth-child(5) {
    background: #3F51B5; /* indigo (blue-purple) */
}
.timeline-img:nth-child(6) {
    background: #2196F3; /* blue */
```

And so on...

However this list will (surely) be constantly modified and the number of childs is unknown, therefore this method will require me to manually add/remove colors everytime.

Thanks for your time and I hope my question is clear.

Comment: can you use LESS or SASS? It would be way easier to implement this using  those.

Comment: @BrianGlaz I just started learning CSS so I would prefer using a method that is straight-forwardly CSS, but I'm eager to learn more. Would you mind suggesting a place to read more about this using LESS/SASS.

Comment: It may be a little complicated if you are just starting, but it would allow you to create and use loops so you wouldn't need to type all the CSS by hand. http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while

Comment: @BrianGlaz thanks alot, I will look into it.